# Как получить JSON с сервера?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Нужно вывести на страницу данные с https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 . Написал такой код:

```
const requestUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';
const postWrapper = document.getElementById('post__wrapper');
let users = [];

const createTemplate = data => {
return template = `
    <div class="wrapper__post">
        <div class="page">PAGE: ${data.page}</div>
        <div class="per_page">PER PAGE: ${data.perPage}</div>
        <div class="total">TOTAL: ${data.total}</div>
        <div class="total_pages">TOTAL PAGES: ${data.totalPages}</div>
        <div class="data">DATA: ${data.data}</div>
    </div>
`
}

const getPosts = url => {
fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
         users = json;
         users.forEach(item => {
             postWrapper.innerHTML += createTemplate(users);
         })
     })
}

getPosts(requestUrl);
```

**Результат:**
[image]

Подскажите, **пожалуйста**, как вывести данные на страницу?

Comment: предлагаю подебажить. например так: fetch(requestUrl).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {console.log(json)}) я например именно так понял в чем дело

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const requestUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';
const postWrapper = document.getElementById('post__wrapper');

const createTemplate = data => {
  
    template = `
        <div class="wrapper__post">
            <div class="page">PAGE: ${data.page}</div>
            <div class="per_page">PER PAGE: ${data.per_page}</div>
            <div class="total">TOTAL: ${data.total}</div>
            <div class="total_pages">TOTAL PAGES: ${data.total_pages}</div>
            
        </div>
    `   
    postWrapper.innerHTML = template
    const allusers = document.querySelector('.wrapper__post');

    users = data.data

    for(let user of users) {
        userdada = `
        <div class="data">DATA: id:${user.id}, email:${user.email}</div>
        `
        allusers.innerHTML += userdada
    }
}  


const getPosts = url => {
fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
        createTemplate(json);
     })
}

getPosts(requestUrl);
```

```html
<div id="post__wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, почему я на stackoverflow запускаю - твой код работает, а когда копирую в свой - у меня такие ошибки: "main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'requestUrl' has already been declared" и "VM83 main.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at createTemplate (VM83 main.js:18)
    at VM83 main.js:26"

Comment: Исключительно моя проблема) Уже решил, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: немного переделал....выспался, называется )

Answer (score 0):

```js
const requestUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';
const postWrapper = document.getElementById('post__wrapper');
let users = [];

const createTemplate = data => {
return template = `
    <div class="wrapper__post">
        <div class="page">PAGE: ${data.page}</div>
        <div class="per_page">PER PAGE: ${data.per_page}</div>
        <div class="total">TOTAL: ${data.total}</div>
        <div class="total_pages">TOTAL PAGES: ${data.total_pages}</div>
        <div class="data">DATA: ${data.data}</div>
    </div>
`;
}

const getPosts = url => {
fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
        json.data = JSON.stringify(json.data);
        postWrapper.innerHTML += createTemplate(json);
     })
}

getPosts(requestUrl);
```

```html
<div id="post__wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Что-то пошло не по плану): "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'requestUrl' has already been declared" и "VM33 main.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at VM33 main.js:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM33 main.js:22"

Comment: @Dikkkey обновил